# Get Wordpress User Profile Url/Link by ID

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I managed to show up the users Profile Images from the mainsite xxxxx.com/ 
in my bbpress forum xxxxx.com/forum/ with the following code:

```
<?php $user_info = get_user_by('id', $wp_query->query_vars['author']); echo get_avatar($user_info->ID, '150'); ?>
```

Question:

How can i get the Users Profile URL/LINK like xxxxxx.com/user/username with the same method?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9):

To get user's profile link like xxxxxx.com/author/username/ use the following function:

```
<?php get_author_posts_url( $author_id, $author_nicename ); ?>
```

Here is the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to edit a user from admin side then you can use this:

```
function get_admin_edit_user_link( $user_id ){

    if ( get_current_user_id() == $user_id )
       $edit_link = get_edit_profile_url( $user_id );
    else
       $edit_link = add_query_arg( 'user_id', $user_id, self_admin_url( 'user-edit.php'));

    return $edit_link;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**User Page URL is working**

wp function => get_author_posts_url( int $author_id, string $author_nicename = '' )

```
<?php echo get_author_posts_url($user_id); ?>

output: https://example.com/author/username/
```

Reference Link : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_link

Answer (score 0):

This function should help: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_author_meta

`the_author_meta( $field, $userID );`

for profile link you'll need 'user_url' for the field

Comment: Just to clarify, `user_url` is the website a user enters when editing their profile (www.mywebsite.com). To get the user author page, e.g., `/author/john-doe` use the `get_author_posts_url($author_id)` method.

Answer (score 0):

For getting user link with its nice name use 2 functions:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_author_posts_url/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/

  get_author_posts_url($user_id, get_the_author_meta('user_nicename', $user_id))